# Firefox doesn't keep settings from about:config

Tags: firefox

Since a update a few weeks ago Firefox doesn't seem to keep settings done in about:config. I noticed this for example because I use a changed dpi setting

```
layout.css.devPixelsPerPx=1.5
```

After an update this was reset to **-1.0**. Changing this to **1.5** again however works only temporarily. After restarting Firefox the setting is gone.

What may be wrong here and how can I fix it?

Comment: I was using the web interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the prefs.js file in the Firefox profile folder with a plain text editor like Notepad and remove the line with the layout.css.devPixelsPerPx pref or change the value to 1.0

```
user_pref("layout.css.devPixelsPerPx", "1.0");
```

From https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/964888

Comment: Thanks, I manually added the key to my user.js and now it seems to work after a reboot. Maybe you could include this information explicitly into your answer then I can accept it.